# Correct way to introduce yourself

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, american-english

In an interview, what is the correct way to introduce yourself?

Some use "myself" and their name, and some use "I'm ___."

I'm confused about what I use.

Please guide me.

Comment: Beginning with _I'm_ is more appropriate, straight and  concise.

Comment: More about success in interview at : http://biginterview.com/blog/2011/09/tell-me-about-yourself.html

Comment: "Myself Andrew Leach" has no verb, so it's very unlikely to be correct. The duplicate covers "Myself am..." which does have a verb but is still wrong. It **may** be correct in some dialect of English, but you haven't used a tag for a specific regional English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach sir i have read it but my Question is differ form it, i want to know which is more effective way to present introduction in american-english

Comment: Well, I think that question does cover it. This question could be improved by quoting actual examples in the question, rather than describing them -- Some use "Myself Rajat Agarwal" and some use "I'm Rajat Agarwal" -- so that what you are asking about is unambiguous. You also need to edit your question to explain why the answers at the other place don't answer your question here.

Comment: Related: [“I myself Naresh” as an introduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143519)